# www-form-urlencoded string parameter not recognized in API communication

Tags: javascript, flask, api-design

It is difficult to give a reproducible exemple, I summarise here the main components:

We have a front-end/back-end system on an ubuntu 18.04 server.
The client side is a web plateform where users can create a project with characteristics (like name, date...).
The front-end is coded in javascript, with a mongoDB behind, and communicates with a flask API. The web link is managed by a dedicated web proxy.

We face a very puzzling behavior we don't understand after days of debugging:

The front-end sends a www-form-urlencoded string parameter X to the API. This parameter is optional and can be empty.

We check that this parameter is in the request body

```
let X = req.body.X? req.body.X : "";
```

If the parameter is set, the requests succeed.
However, if the parameter is omitted a weird behavior happens in the API :

- The HTTP request is received, we can read a few key properties such as requested URL, headers and such
- When accessing the property request.form, a dict containing the parameters as key-value pairs, the API freezes.
- After a short time the requests timesout frontEnd side
- After the timeout, Flask resolves the request with a 400 BAD REQUEST code without raising any exception or calling a set error handler for the 400 code.

Answer (score 0):

We eventually found the reason why it failed. I document it here for the next one:
The development version used the 'got' library for the http request. For whatever reason (we are still investigating and I will complete the answer once we find more), the request with an empty string failed for 'got'. We switched to the 'axios' library and all went fine.